# XQuery adding or replacing attribute in single SQL update command

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, xquery-sql

I have a Table with an XML column,
I want to update the xml to insert attribute or to change the attribute value if the attribute already exists.

Let's say the starting xml is: < d />

*Inserting:*

```
UPDATE Table 
set XmlCol.modify('insert attribute att {"1"} into /d[1]')
```

*Changing:*

```
UPDATE Table
set XmlCol.modify('replace value of /d[1]/@att with "1"')
```

insert will fail if the attribute already exists, replace will fail if the attribute doesn't exists. 
I have tried to use 'if' but I don't think it can work, there error I get: "XQuery [modify()]: Syntax error near 'attribute', expected 'else'."

*IF attempt*

```
UPDATE Table 
set XmlCol.modify('if empty(/d[1]/@att) 
                   then insert attribute att {"1"} into /d[1]
                   else replace value of /d[1]/@att with "1"')
```

Currently I select the xml into a variable and then modify it using T-SQL and then updating the column with new xml, this requires me to lock the row in a transaction and is probably more expensive for the DB.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, you can't do this with single statement. You can use the [exist() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) to accomplish that with two update statements.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
    Id int,
    XmlCol xml
);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Id, XmlCol)
VALUES
    (1, '<d att="1" />'),
    (2, '<d />'),
    (3, '<d att="3" />');

SELECT * FROM @TestTable;

UPDATE @TestTable
SET XmlCol.modify('replace value of /d[1]/@att with "1"')
WHERE XmlCol.exist('(/d[1])[not(empty(@att))]') = 1;

UPDATE @TestTable
SET XmlCol.modify('insert attribute att {"1"} into /d[1]')
WHERE XmlCol.exist('(/d[1])[empty(@att)]') = 1;

SELECT * FROM @TestTable;
```

The output from the final select is:

```
Id          XmlCol
----------- -------------------
1           <d att="1" />
2           <d att="1" />
3           <d att="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly better way than Tommys:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
    Id int,
    XmlCol xml
);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Id, XmlCol)
VALUES
    (1, '<UserSettings> </UserSettings>'),
    (2, '<UserSettings><timeout>3</timeout> </UserSettings>'),
    (3, '<UserSettings> </UserSettings>');

UPDATE @TestTable
SET XmlCol.modify('replace value of (/UserSettings/timeout/text())[1] with "1"')
WHERE Id = 3 and XmlCol.exist('/UserSettings/timeout') = 1;
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    UPDATE @TestTable
    SET XmlCol.modify('insert <timeout>5</timeout> into (/UserSettings)[1] ')
    WHERE Id = 3;

SELECT * FROM @TestTable;
```

The solution is a combination of Tommys and simple SQL and required only 1 SQL UPDATE if the column exist. Tommys always recuire two updates.